# How to rsync to a server that does not have rsync but has the SCP tool

Tags: linux, rsync, scp, freebsd

The remote server is a FreeBSD like system from which rsync is not installed :

```shell
$ ssh admin@x.y.z.t which rsync scp
Password:
rsync not found
/usr/local/bin/scp
$ rsync -a /ring/0/share/Archives_AudioVisuel/TEST admin@x.y.z.t:/ifs/par-nas01/data/MPP/ADN_Archives/Audiovisuels/
Password:
zsh:1: command not found: rsync
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]
$
```

I tried adding `-e ssh` but I get the same error saying `rsync` is `not found`.

And if I try adding `--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/scp` but then I get a `scp: illegal option -- -` error.

How can I do a `rsync` to a server that only has the `scp` tool ?

Comment: If you could copy a binary of `rsync` to the server, you could use that binary with `--rsync-path=/path/to/rsync` (path to the binary).

Comment: @harrymc I don't have the right to run `pkg update`, so I won't be able to install the `rsync` package. Where then can I download `rsync` binary for FreeBSD ?

Comment: Might be [here](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/binaries/freebsd-12.1-x86_64/).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @harrymc The `admin` account does not have the rights on `/usr/local/bin/` so I cannot extract it there.

Comment: You can put it in any folder to which you have access. It doesn't matter where, since the path is specified in the command.

Comment: "_I don't have the right to run pkg update_" - so it's a managed system. Ask in the appropriate place for the rsync tool to be installed. That might be your manager/supervisor, or your system administrator, or even your change board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to install software on the remote FreeBSD machine, but can install software on your local Linux machine, you may use [`sshfs`](https://en.WikiPedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) as a workaround.

```sh
mkdir my_mountpoint
# The pathname (here just a slash) indicates the root of the mounted FS.
sshfs admin@remote_machine:/ $_
```

The `sshfs` command starts the `/usr/libexec/sftp-server` command *on the remote* FreeBSD machine, a *pre‑installed* binary.
Now you can use your mount point as if it was in the global pathname namespace.
Remember the `${_}` shell variable expands to the previous command’s last argument.

```sh
rsync -a /ring/0/share/Archives_AudioVisuel/TEST \
    ${_}/ifs/par-nas01/data/MPP/ADN_Archives/Audiovisuels/
```

Once you are done, unmount the FUSE (filesystem in userspace) mount with the `fusermount` utility.

```sh
fusermount -u my_mountpoint
```

I am afraid this method will not make *full* use of rsync’s efficient Δ‑copying algorithms though.
If you are synchronizing video archives, this should not be too crucial, I guess.